# Gradle zip task neither failing nor working

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to create a custom Gradle 4.3.1 task that will:

1. Run `./gradlew build` which produces a `build/libs/myapp.jar` artifact; then
2. Creates a `myapp-1.0.zip` ZIP file whose contents include:

   - `build/libs/myapp.jar`; and
   - `./AppGuide.md`; and
   - `./app-config.json`

Here's my best attempt:

```
task zipMeUp(type: Zip) {
  String zipName = 'myapp-1.0.zip'

  doFirst {
    tasks.build
  }

  from 'build/libs/myapp.jar'
  from 'AppGuide.md'
  from 'app-config.json'
  into zipName
}
```

When I run this (`./gradlew zipMeUp`) I get the following output:

```
HarveyZ:myapp myuser$ ./gradlew zipMeUp

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

But nothing actually seems to happen (no `myapp-1.0.zip` file in the directory). **Any idea what the fix/solution is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `doFirst`, use `dependsOn`

```
task zipMeUp(type:Zip, dependsOn :[build]) {
    String zipName = 'myapp-1.0.zip'

    from 'build/libs/myapp.jar'
    from 'AppGuide.md'
    from 'app-config.json'

    version = "1.0"
    baseName = "myapp"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Taub (+1) are you sure `packJar`/`Jar` task is the correct task type to depend on though? This is actually a Spring Boot application that adds some very specific Gradle capabilities and requires `./gradlew build` to be ran in order to build it correctly (creates a self-contained executable JAR with embedded Jetty container, does a lot of other magic, etc.)

Comment: you are right i just didn't no that you using spring to pack your jar